# Using CAS Addons, missing xsd

Tags: java, authentication, cas, jasig

https://github.com/Unicon/cas-addons/wiki/Dynamic-Login-View-Selector

This plugin example for CAS has a missing xsd.
XSD declared is http://unicon.net/schema/cas/cas-addons.xsd .

Not able to proceed without this xsd, since Spring beans xml needs this for newer tags as given in the above link. 
How do I solve this problem?